# How to change the language speech

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

```
def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'whisper' in command:
                command = command.replace('whisper', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command
```

I want to change the language in which the program speaks.

Answer (score 0):

You add a language argument. In this example Bulgarian:

> listener.recognize_google(voice, language='bg-BG')

Here is the link to supported languages and their codes: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-to-text-supported-languages